# Echo set color for variable

Tags: colors, echo

I have this code

```html
<?php
$date1=date('d.M',strtotime("+1 days"));
$date2=date('d.M',strtotime("+2 days"));

echo 'Ajunge la tine ' ,$date1, ' - ' ,$date2 ;

?>
```

I what in echo to set color red for $date1 and $date2 .

Thanx

Comment: Do you want set CSS for value of two variable?

Comment: Yes css or any method to change color to red !

Comment: I found a solution <?php
$date1=date('d.M',strtotime("+1 days"));
$date2=date('d.M',strtotime("+2 days"));

echo 'Ajunge la tine<font color=\"red\"><b> ' ,$date1, ' - ' ,$date2, '</b></font> prin curier.' ;

?>

Comment: :) You should remove your question. Or post new answer/update answer for your question with the method resolved your problem.